Detail regarding Sherman-Morrison formula with $A=I$
I was going through the exercises of "Linear Algebra and It's Applications" by Gilbert Strang . I came across this question in inverse and transposes:

$M^{-1}$ shows the change in $A^{-1}$(useful to know) when a matrix is
subtracted from $A$. Check part 3 by carefully multiplying $MM^{-1}$ to
get $I$:

$M=I-uv^{T}$  and  $$ M ^{-1}= I + \frac{uv^T}{1 - v^Tu} $$

$M = A -uv ^T$ and  $$M ^ {-1} = A ^ {- 1 }+ \frac{A ^ {- 1 }u v ^ T A ^ {- 1} }{ 1 - v ^ T  A ^ {- 1} u} $$

$M = I - UV$
and $$M ^ {- 1} = I_{n} + U(I_{m} - VU) ^ {- 1}V$$

$M = A - UW ^ {- 1 } V$  and $$ M ^ {- 1 }= A ^ {- 1} + A ^{ - 1}  U (W - V A ^ {- 1} U) ^ {- 1} V  A ^{ - 1}$$


The four identities come from the $(1, 1) $block when inverting these
matrices:
$\begin{bmatrix} I &u\\ v^{T} &1 \end{bmatrix} $$ \begin{bmatrix}
 A&u\\v^{T}&1 \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix} I_n &U\\ V &I_m
\end{bmatrix} $ $\begin{bmatrix} A&U\\ V &W \end{bmatrix} $

Now I sorted out the inverse of the  matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} I &u\\ v^{T} &1 \end{bmatrix} $$
i.e.
$$\begin{bmatrix} I+\frac{uv^{T}}{1-v^Tu} &\frac{-u}{1-v^{T}u}\\ \frac{-v^{T}}{1-v^{T}u} &\frac{1}{1-v^{T}u} \end{bmatrix} $$
It is clear from here what is meant by the statement that the inverse are found in the $(1,1)$ block of the inverse of the matrix .
But the real question is how do we know whose inverse does it represent i.e. how do we know that it's the inverse of $$M=I-uv^{T}$$
How can one see it from that matrix?
I know it can be shown by multiplying the two matrices $M$ and $M^{-1}$ but how could we randomly guess any matrix $M$ which does the work?
In one sentence:
From where $M$ came and how do we know that a particular matrix would give its inverse?

To verify that you have the correct form for $M^{-1}$ calculate $MM^{-1}$ and see if it equals $I$.

Number 4 is known as the Woodbury Matrix Identity. Number 2 is known as the Sherman-Morrison formula, and is a special case. It might help you to look up these formulas, and see if you can find some more information. As for your question, I'm not sure what you're looking for. The last sentence of your quote points you to the "bigger picture" way of recognising these formulas, and as you said, you can prove them directly by multiplication. What more are you looking for?

@TheoBendit I am asking that how do we know what is $M$ as only then we could multiply both to find $I$

The four formulae in your question can be derived from the following generalisation of $(3)$, namely,
$$
(\lambda I-UV)^{-1}
=\lambda^{-1}I+\lambda^{-1}U(\lambda I-VU)^{-1}V,\tag{$\#$}
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are square matrices and $\lambda$ is a scalar. To prove this identity, pick any submultiplicative matrix norm, such as Frobenius norm $\|X\|=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(X^\ast X}$ or the operator norm $\|X\|=\max_{\|v\|_2=1}\|Xv\|_2$ induced by the $2$-norm. (A matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ is called submultiplicative if $\|XY\|\le\|X\|\|Y\|$ for all square matrices $X$ and $Y$.) Now, when $\lambda$ is sufficiently large, we have $|\lambda^{-1}|\|U\|\|V\|<1$. Therefore the Neumann series $I+\lambda^{-1}UV+(\lambda^{-1}UV)^2+\cdots$ converges absolutely and one may easily verify that
$$
(I-\lambda^{-1}UV)\left[I+\lambda^{-1}UV+(\lambda^{-1}UV)^2+\cdots\right]=I.
$$
Therefore $(I-\lambda^{-1}UV)^{-1}=I+\lambda^{-1}UV+(\lambda^{-1}UV)^2+\cdots$. Similarly, $(I-\lambda^{-1}VU)^{-1}=I+\lambda^{-1}VU+(\lambda^{-1}VU)^2+\cdots$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
(\lambda I-UV)^{-1}
&=\lambda^{-1}(I-\lambda^{-1}UV)^{-1}\\
&=\lambda^{-1}\left[I+\lambda^{-1}UV+(\lambda^{-1}UV)^2+(\lambda^{-1}UV)^3+\cdots\right]\\
&=\lambda^{-1}I+\lambda^{-2}U\left[I+\lambda^{-1}VU+(\lambda^{-1}VU)^2+\cdots\right]V\\
&=\lambda^{-1}I+\lambda^{-2}U(I-\lambda^{-1}VU)^{-1}V\\
&=\lambda^{-1}I+\lambda^{-1}U(\lambda-VU)^{-1}V.\\
\end{align*}
That is,
$$
\lambda q(\lambda)\operatorname{adj}(\lambda I-UV)
=p(\lambda)\left[q(\lambda)I+U\operatorname{adj}(\lambda I-VU)V\right]
$$
for all sufficiently large $\lambda$, where $p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-UV)$ and $q(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-VU)$ are the characteristic polynomials of $UV$ and $VU$ respectively. Since the two sides of the equality above are polynomials and they agree at infinitely many values of $\lambda$, they must be identical to each other in $\mathbb C$. Consequently, the two sides of $(\#)$ have the same poles, and they are identical whenever either side is defined.
In short, $(\#)$ arises from expanding $(I-\lambda^{-1}UV)^{-1}$ as a Neumann series. If we put $\lambda=1$, we immediately get $(3)$. Formula (4) follows by replacing $U$ and $V$ with $A^{-1}U$ and $W^{-1}V$. Formula (1) also follows from (3) by putting $U=ue_1^T$ and $V=e_1v^T$. Subsequently, (2) follows from (1) by replacing $u$ with $A^{-1}u$. Thus formulae (2) and (4), which obviously imply (1) and (3), are not genuine generalisations but disguises of the latter two formulae.

The grandparent of all four formulae in your question is the universal identity
$$
(\lambda-ab)^{-1}
=\lambda^{-1}+\lambda^{-1}a(\lambda-ba)^{-1}b\tag{$\#$}
$$
in the ring of formal Laurent series in the indeterminate $\lambda$ over $\mathbb Z\langle a,b\rangle$. This identity is a consequence of another universal identity,
$$
(1-x)^{-1}
=1+x+x^2+\cdots,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
in the ring $\mathbb Z((x))$ of formal Laurent series in the indeterminate $x$ over $\mathbb Z$. The identity $(\ast)$ is obviously true because $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)=1$. Therefore, by specialising $x$ to $ab\lambda^{-1}$ and $ba\lambda^{-1}$, we get
\begin{align*}
(\lambda-ab)^{-1}
&=\lambda^{-1}(1-\lambda^{-1}ab)^{-1}\\
&=\lambda^{-1}\left[1+\lambda^{-1}ab+\lambda^{-2}(ab)^2+\lambda^{-3}(ab)^3+\cdots\right]\\
&=\lambda^{-1}+\lambda^{-2}a\left[1+\lambda^{-1}ba+\lambda^{-2}(ba)^2+\cdots\right]b\\
&=\lambda^{-1}+\lambda^{-2}a(1-\lambda^{-1}ba)^{-1}b\\
&=\lambda^{-1}+\lambda^{-1}a(\lambda-ba)^{-1}b.
\end{align*}
(See more discussions about $(\#)$ and $(\ast)$ on MO.)
Clearly, $(\#)$ gives $(3)$ if we put $a=U,b=V$ and specialise $\lambda$ to $I$. Formula (4) follows from (3) by replacing $U$ and $V$ with $A^{-1}U$ and $W^{-1}V$. Formula (1) also follows from (3) by putting $U=ue_1^T$ and $V=e_1v^T$. Formula (2) follows from (1) by replacing $u$ with $A^{-1}u$. Thus formulae (2) and (4), which obviously imply (1) and (3), are not genuine generalisations but disguises of the latter two formulae.

That was very helpful in understanding the proofs.Can you please expand on what a ring is what what is meant by $\mathbb Z\langle a,b\rangle$ and what is $\lambda$ exactly? And, can we interpret a and b as a column vector and row vector respectively and why? As, I am very new to these notions.

@CPofPhysics These notions are very basic in abstract algebra. They are not difficult, but they cannot be explained in a few words. I will see if I can write another answer that is more accessible to those without training in abstract algebra.

That would be very kind of you!!
